# Javascript - how to encode special characters from text file for autopopulate text field

Tags: javascript, escaping, encode, html-entities

I have a text file that I get for my auto-populate textfield function. The problem is, how do I encode the contents of the text file so there will be no more special characters? please help...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) and [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) functions for this.